# Difference in weight while pulling weights

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, everyday-life, free-body-diagram

Let's say you are using a standard pulley gym machine to lift some amount of weight. If while you exercise you are standing on a weighing scale. What variations in weight if any would occur?
Does it depend on the position of the weights? For example would you increase in weight until it reaches what would essentially be your center of mass?

I think your weight increases while while the weights are going up (you are pulling) and decreases back to your original weight on it's weight down. Probably some scale jitter when you start pulling.

Comment: It depends on the configuration. Are you making force to raise or to lower the bar?

Comment: You are using your arms to pull down on the bar, which would raise the weights up.

Comment: Thought experiment: How much would the scale read when pulling down on a 1000lb bar? The answer is zero, since you're not heavy enough to move the bar down at all - you'll just wind up doing a pullup, at which point you're not even touching the scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends which type of machine it is, quite simply.

If it is the type that are pulled upwards (which have multiple pulleys), then it will add the amount of force you are applying to your weight.

If it is the type that are pulled downwards (which usually have only one pulley and therefore the force required is equal to the weight), then it will reduce your scale reading accordingly.

In regard as to when it adds how much, I am not sure. I would assume that as soon as the weights are relying entirely upon you to hold them aloft, their weight would be added/taken away, but as my old gym teacher used to say, to assume makes an ass out of you (u) and me...

Answer (score 1):

It is actually the opposite, the weight in the balance will go down in the same amount than the force applied to the bar attached to the pulley. This is because the force this bar makes on the person is upwards. The only way the weight in the scale will mark more is if you are pushing something up (but not if slowly releasing it up, because you are still making a down force in such a case)

Comment: So it will be acting as a counterweight to your body ? Say for example if you are lifting 50kgs using the machine (let's say the bar is weightless for simplicity) and you weight 80kgs when not using the machine. While pulling the scale under your feet would register 30kgs?

Comment: the pulley, as a machine,  will change the force so you need less force to raise the weights, but yes, it is a counterweight. Imagine the weight is so large that you just hang on it, the balance will measure zero

Comment: Indeed, you can't pull down a bar that's heavier than you are without strapping yourself down somehow. This is precisely why most of those pull-down machines have pads for your thighs, so that you don't get pulled *up* by the bar. A person using these pads to lift more than their weight would actually have a *negative* apparent weight, since they would accelerate *upward* if not restrained!

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible scenarios as pointed out by other users, but I'll focus on the following one:

Consider the case where the weights are pulled downwards. For the sake of simplicity, let's assume we're just holding the weight (so we can ignore the shifting center of mass, since a human is not a rigid body).

Observe the diagram, where a human of mass $M$ is holding a weight of mass $m$ using 1 (assumed massless and frictionless) pulley:

[image]

Note that the magnitude of the normal force $\mathbf N$ is what the scale will read. As you can see, the upwards tension will decrease the required normal force for the human to remain stationary.

Edit: yes, the normal force will be exerted at the person's feet (so in two spots), but the way I drew it makes the magnitude of the normal force clearer.